# Will Ansible tasks run or not?

Tags: ansible

Hello I have the following task structure which I got from a previous IT guy who worked before me.

```
- hosts: "{{env}}"
  vars:
    workspace: "{{ hostvars[localhost]['workspace'] }}"
    post_build: false
  tasks:
 - name: Delete log module folder on remote
    file: blabla
    state=absent
    when: post_build

 - name: Copy login folder to remote
   copy:src='blabla'
   when: post_build
```

Will the tasks run or not? Because the `post_build` variable is set to `false` at the begining. But the tasks runs only with `post_build` being true. In this case why we need that tasks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tasks will not run if the variables were set only in the play.

But values defined in play can be overridden by defining variables on a different level, for example with `--extra-vars` parameter in the execution line.

Read about [variable precedence](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

The author of the playbook might wanted the tasks to be run only when explicitly specified elsewhere.

---

Besides, please pay attention to indentation and decide for a single convention, i.e. do not mix pure YAML (`parameter: value`) with Ansible notation (`parameter=value`).